# List of chapters epub siegmann epublib

Tags: android, epub

I can take list of chapters title

```
private void logTableOfContents(List<TOCReference> tocReferences, int depth) {
    if (tocReferences == null) {
        return;
    }

    for (TOCReference tocReference : tocReferences) {
        StringBuilder tocString = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i < depth; i++) {
            tocString.append("\t");
        }
        tocString.append(tocReference.getTitle());

        Log.i("epublib", tocString.toString());
        logTableOfContents(tocReference.getChildren(), depth + 1);

    }

}
```

How to move to line in Resource where this chapter  started?

Comment: Just to mention that, in EPUB 2, there is no notion of "chapter". The fact that in most EPUB files, XHTML files correspond to chapters, and they are listed in the NCX TOC, is more a convention than a formal requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! All epub books have  tag with chapters id